# delphi Convert minutes in hours to minutes

Tags: delphi

ello i do not know how write a delphi program that take the number of minutes it took to get from point A to point B in an suitable input component e.g. 65 mintes is 1 hour and 5 minutes now my question is how wil write it?

Comment: You should consider revising your question with some clarity, I have a foggy idea what you're asking, and it has been answered and accepted, but it is difficult to understand the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this with `div` and `mod`, the [integer division and modulus operators](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Expressions_%28Delphi%29#Arithmetic_Operators).

```
procedure ConvertMinutesToHoursAndMinutes(
  Input: Integer; out Hours, Minutes: Integer);
begin
  Hours := Input div 60;
  Minutes := Input mod 60;
end;
```

Comment: how will i do that with DIV and MOD

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot understand that comment. You just need to use the code in the answer. It's right there for you.

Comment: ok so the coding should look like this then

Comment: unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
procedure ConvertMinutesToHoursAndMinutes(
  Input: Integer; out Hours, Minutes: Integer);
begin
  Hours := Input div 60;
  Minutes := Input mod 60;
end;

end.

Comment: The question asks how to convert minutes into hours and minutes. That I answered. I don't want to write the entire program.

Answer (score 2):

A nice formatting routine may be like this:

```
function MinutesToStrEx(const Minutes: Cardinal): string;
var
  D, H, M: Integer;
begin
  H := M div 60;
  M := M mod 60;
  D := H div 24;
  H := H mod 24;
  if D > 0 then
    if (H <> 0) or (M <> 0) then
      Result := Format('%d days %d hours and %d minutes', [D, H, M])
    else
      Result := Format('%d days', [D]);
  else if H > 0 then
    if M > 0 then
      Result := Format('%d hours and %d minutes', [H, M])
    else
      Result := Format('%d minutes', [M]);
end;
```

Then you call it like this:

```
begin
  Label1.Caption := 'Ellapsed time to reach from A to B: ' + MinutesToStrEx(Minutes);
end;
```